# Can't get my delete method to work for SQLite database using android

Tags: android, sqlite

I can't get one of my delete methods to work in Android using SQLite.  Here is my code to open the datasource and call the appropriate methods.

```
DataSource ds = new DataSource(getApplicationContext());
ds.open();
Term term = ds.getSingleTermById(termNo);
long id = term.getId();
ds.deleteCoursesByTermId(id);
ds.deleteTerm(term);
ds.close();
```

Here is my `deleteCoursesByTermId()` method:

```
//Delete all courses by term id
public void deleteCoursesByTermId(long id){
    db.delete(DBOpenHelper.COURSE_TABLE, DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + " = ?",
            new String[] {Long.toString(id)});
}
```

In fact none of the methods I set up to delete a row based on ID are working properly, here is an example:

```
//Delete single term by id
public void deleteTermById(long id){
    db.delete(DBOpenHelper.TERMS_TABLE, DBOpenHelper.KEY_ID + " = " + id, null);
}
```

Why aren't these methods working?

Comment: Can you read the same row with `query()`?

Comment: Are you sure that `KEY_ID` is meant to be `term_id` of a course ? or it is the column that represents `course_id`. I mean are you sure of your deleting condition

Comment: More problems  Sometimes things actually don't work.  public void when you should return the result of db.delete.  for the singe term by id delete